# Make TestDouble method behave differently depending on test case

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have a Wrapper class in C# called `MyService` for a `ThirdPartyService` API. I would like to create some tests for this `MyService` to make sure I'm handling all cases as expected.

`ThirdPartyService` has the following methods that it exposes and which we consume in different places through `MyService` wrapper.

- `MethodToCreate`

As it is a third party service, I don't know the business logic wrapped inside it. So I can't create a test double for that service directly as it is a library that we use.

However the third party library often returns errors when different types of bad things happen, like

- when there is a network problem
- when there is a timeout in communicating with any other underlying services
- when the third party service is down
- many other cases

It also returns the actual results when things are working fine. 
I'd like to create a `MyServiceTestDouble` class that would help me test every type of interaction with ThirdPartyService cases.

So `IMyService` and `MyService` would look something like this (just an example, only one method):

```
public interface IMyService
{
     int MethodToCreate(string arg1, string arg2);
}

public class MyService : IMyService
{
    private readonly ThirdPartyService _thirdPartyService;

    public MyService()
    {
         _thirdPartyService = new ThirdPartyService();
    }

    public int MethodToCreate(string arg1, string arg2)
    {
        var thirdPartyServiceTypeArg = ParseStringToThirdPartyServiceArg(arg1);
        return _thirdPartyService.MethodToCreate(thirdParthyServiceTypeArg, arg2);
    }        
}

public class MyServiceTestDouble : IMyService
{
    public MyServiceTestDouble()
    {

    }

    public int MethodToCreate(string arg1, string arg2)
    {
        return (new Random).Next();
    }
}

public static class MyServiceFactory
{
    public static IMyService GetMyService()
    {
        if(!Config.IsTestMode) return new MyService();
        return new MyServiceTestDouble();
    }
}
```

---

But I'm stuck where I need to make the methods in `MyServiceTestDouble` return different types of output depending on my unit test. 
Like when it is a good case that I am testing, I would like it to return proper actual results. 
When my test case is for testing Exceptions, I would like the methods in `MyServiceTestDouble` to return appropriate exceptions.

*What is the best approach to do this?*

The one approach I think that will work is to create a `MyServiceFactory` that returns different Test Double Implementations based on the Unit test case scenario. But this would mean I need to have multiple implementations of `MyServiceTestDouble` like `MyServiceTestDoubleGood`. `MyServiceTestDoubleNetworkExceptions`, `MyServiceTestOutageExceptions` etc. 
I'm pretty sure that there could be a better way that I'm currently not aware of.

I would like to know if there are any unit testing framework that would help with this sort of testing.

I would also like to know if this is possible in a more elegant way without using any frameworks.

Comment: I you have a wrapper class.. then how come you can't add some Methods to that class.. can you show what you have so that one can gain a better understanding of what you're trying to do..?

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted. thanks for that and not being helpful and defeating the purpose of the discussion.

Comment: You don't need multiple implementations, you just need a constructor argument that defines the behaviour of the double. Btw, I am upvoting this question as it makes perfect sense.

Comment: Your constructors in your two classes seem to be flip flopped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better solution would be to use the [`moq`](https://github.com/Moq/moq4) library, which has shorthand methods for returning data or different kinds of exceptions depending on special input values. So you can say, if input is 1, throw an error; if input is 3, return data, etc., like that.

Installation is [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Moq/)

The [Getting Started](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) has some examples:

```cs
using Moq;

var mockMyService = new Mock<IMyService>();
mockMyService.Setup(o => o.MethodToCreate("arg1", "arg2")).Returns(4);
mockMyService.Setup(o => o.MethodToCreate("cut","cable")).Throws(new NetworkException("the network is down"));
```

Or, you can mimic this feature of moq in your dummy class with a switch statement:

```cs
public int MethodToCreate(string arg1, string arg2)
{
    switch(arg1){
      case "a":
        throw new Exception(); // throw exception
      case "z":
        return 4; // good data
    }
}
```

Comment: I got the idea. Thanks for the answer.